# Adding row to Datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-table, datalist

I have been searching around the web for a solution to this issue but have come across nothing so far.

Basically I have a table as shown below, which I made up of `ItemTemplate` fields and is populated by a DataSet from my database. It shows brands to the user of which they can then click and go onto another page.

I need to add another option to the table called "All Brands". Thus then I can use this to go to a page showing all the brands. However I can not seem to easily add this into the DataList.

```
<asp:DataList id="TypesList" runat="server" Visible="true" RepeatColumns="3" Width="100%" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="position:relative;vertical-align:top;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="height:170px;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;" valign="top">
            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"batteryTypeID")%>'></asp:Label>

            <a href='/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"catid")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"catname")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brandid")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brand_name")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"batteryTypeID")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"typeName")%>' target='_self'>
              <asp:Image ID="imgProd" runat="server" ImageUrl='images/none.jpg' />
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="productdesc" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
            <span style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;font-size:120%;">
              <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "typeName").ToString%>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: It's not really clear from your question - could it be that simply adding a `HeaderTemplate` or `FooterTemplate` will give the possiblity to place a link to "All Brands" to your DataList. Maybe add a simple example of your desired result to make it clearer what you're looking for.

Comment: This is what I am aiming for. Having an extra row showing "All Types" as an option. Have a look at this image example. http://postimage.org/image/h61uxssxf/

Comment: Filburt's spot on.  Add this default entry to your Header or Footer Template as there is no association between the data if you want keep things in the DataList.  Alternatively, why not add the additional entry outside of the DataList, you're not particular using any superstructured HTML output there...

Comment: BTW, tables nested in DIVs for not tabluar data, I haven't seen that kinda of styling for a few years now.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html

Comment: The only problem with using the header or footer template, is that it is then not just another cell in the table. It does not conform to the same layout. I have removed the html table. That was what a predecessor of mine did . . . no idea why . . . here is a screenshot of what it looks like now. http://postimage.org/image/wt385c6g5/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this with the following layout:

```
<asp:DataList id="TypesList" runat="server" Visible="true" RepeatColumns="3" Width="100%" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">

  <HeaderTemplate>
    <div style="width:170px; float:left;">
      <div>All Brands Pic and Link</div>
      <div>
        <span style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;font-size:120%;">All Brands</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </HeaderTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="width:170px; float:left;">
      <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"batteryTypeID")%>'></asp:Label>
        <a href='/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"catid")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"catname")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brandid")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brand_name")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"batteryTypeID")%>/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"typeName")%>' target='_self'>
          <asp:Image ID="imgProd" runat="server" ImageUrl='images/none.jpg' />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;font-size:120%;">
          <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "typeName").ToString%>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

My css is a little rusty but I trust people will be happy to point out how it could be styled better.